# an example how to produce ''end if'', ''end for'', and ''end while'' in the algorithm2e environment?

Tags: algorithm2e

Could anyone show me by an example how to produce ''end if'', ''end for'',  and ''end while'' in the algorithm2e environment? Hello, thank you for your answer, I have tried to upload the algorithm which I want to write In the algorithm2e environment, I have also tried doing some portion of that but could you please help me to make it error-free and completed? Thanks

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ruled, noline]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
```

[image: Here is my algorithm]

```
\begin{algorithm}
\SetKw{KwBy}{by}
\SetAlgoLined
\DontPrintSemicolon
$k\gets 0$

$M_a\gets 0$

$M_b\gets 0$

\lWhile{something}{

\For{$p \in \{a,b\}$}{

\lIf{something}{

$M_p \gets M_p +1$
 
something

\Else

\If{M_p=M}{

something


\EndIf

\Else{something}
}
}
}
$k\gets k + 1$

\If{$M_a = M$ and $M_b = M$}{
        $M_a \gets 0$
        
        $M_b \gets 0$
        }
        }
        \end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Don't load `algpseudocode` along with `algorithm2e` and don't mix syntax: the two packages are *different* and don't go along together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `noend` from `algorithm2e` arguments. `noend` specifically tells the package not to render end-statements.

Here is your MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ruled, noline]{algorithm2e} % <-- HERE
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Your algorithm}
    
        $i\gets 10$\;
        \eIf{$i\geq 5$}
        {
            $i\gets i-1$\;
        }{
            \If{$i\leq 3$}
            {
                $i\gets i+2$\;
            }
        }
    \end{algorithm}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, I have tried to upload the algorithm which I want to write In the algorithm2e environment, I have also tried doing some portion of that but could you please help me to make it error-free and completed? Thanks